# Automatically start a timer after logging health record

Tags: iphone, automation, shortcuts-app, health.app, time

I take a medication that needs 30mn to be assimilated by my body before eating anything in the morning. I log it every morning in the Health app to not forget it as it is quite important.

I was wondering if there is a way with Shortcuts or other to automatically create a 30mn timer when completing the health app logging? Setting it manually is quite tidious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an automation that will work.

Under Automations select the App trigger.

Select when Health app is Closed to Run. (In the tests I just ran, I found triggering the shortcut when opening the app the screen got too busy, on closing the app there seems to be less chance of accidentally closing the shortcut notification).

Then set a timer shortcut.

I would recommend using Run after Confirmation for this type of automation as it involves medication so you really want to know it's activated. Also this means that you won't have an alarm every time you close the Health App as you are given the option so if your in the app for something else, you. can cancel the shortcut.

My test I did, this worked flawlessly.

[image]

Comment: That's so clever! Didn't think of this option. Thank you 

Comment: No dramas, hopefully it suits what you need.

Comment: I actually figured that logging the entry from the notification (long press) doesn't open the app so doesn't start the timer but heh, that's good enough.

Comment: Ah bugger. I log mine from the notification which is what I used in my tests. I keep forgetting about long press menus.

Answer (score 0):

There are no automation options to run a shortcut on logging a health record. Instead, it should be possible to create a shortcut that logs the medication, and could then start a timer. However, it is not possible to log medication from Shortcuts, so this is currently not possible either. Therefore there is no solution at present.